# Search dictionary of string arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming

I'd like to look for a string value in a dictionary of ints mapped to arrays of strings. I can get the below code to work for a dictionary of ints mapped to strings, but not string arrays. How can I do this? I tried nesting another filter inside my filter, but no luck.

```
let dict = [1 : ["one", "two"], 2 : ["red", "green"], 3 : ["World", "are", "you"]]

// Doesn't work for array of strings.
let keys = dict.filter {
    return $0.1.containsString("are")  // Should return 3
}.map {
    return $0.0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `contains` instead.

```
let keys = dict
  .filter {$0.1.contains("are")}
  .map { $0.0 }
```

This returns 3.